# Rails: Custom Validation :on => :update Running During :create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have the following in my controller:

```
def create
  group = Group.create(params[:group])
end
```

And this in my model:

```
validate :governance_style_change, :on => :update

. . . .

private

  def governance_style_change
    if self.governance_style_was != 3
      errors.add(:governance_style, I18n.t("group.errors.cannot_change_governance_style"))
    end
  end
```

For some reason, the validation is running during `create`. Have I done something wrong?

Comment: just a sanity check :D are you sure you're not calling the method somewhere else?

Comment: This code looks fine. The problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: As @jvnill suspects, something else must be saving your group object. Perhaps another validation, such as an after_save that then ultimately re-saves the object?

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, though tracking down the actual problem is proving difficult. Searching my whole project, I get only two results for `governance_style_change`--the one in which I call in a validation and the one in which I define it. So that's not being directly called. That probably means MrDanA is right, though there are no `after_create` or `after_save` callbacks that save this model. Is there another way the object might get updated?

Comment: Found the problem. One of the `after_create`s created another model which called `validates_associated :group`. @Mr.DanA had it right, though apparently I didn't even have to save the `group` object. Simply calling a validation seems to be enough to count as `:on => :update`.

Comment: just put `puts caller` into that validation and see where it gets called from. alternatively use a debugging tool like pry or the ruby debugger.

Comment: @timothythehuman It would be valuable if you could add your comment as an answer.